# How does Knockout know to update the binding of a descendent property when the object it exists on is replaced?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got something to work, but I'm really confused about how it's happening. I'm a noob and could really use your help.

Here is a jsbin that demonstrates my question:
http://jsbin.com/notakeniwu/5/edit?html,js,output

I'm confused about how the descendent property binding is maintaining its connection even when the parent object is replaced.

So, say I make a new instance of an object and then bind something on the DOM to a property of this new instance (this new object is being referenced from my view model) just before I apply KO bindings. If I make a new instance of this object later and update the reference in my view model (using the object's observable) the descendent property maintains its connection to the DOM even though I did not replace it through its observable. It is a totally new property. How is this happening? How would the DOM side know to replace the property to which it's bound?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-bind="with: person">
      <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var Person = function (name) {
  this.human = true;
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.person = ko.observable(new Person("Wayne"));
  this.createPerson = function () {
    this.person(new Person("Garth"));
  };
  this.changeName = function(name) {
    this.person().name(name);
  };
};

window.test = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(window.test);

// this is where I'm confused
setTimeout(test.createPerson.bind(test),1000);
setTimeout(function () {
   test.changeName("WoOoOoOo"); 
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `person` is also observable, and you're binding to that as well:

```
<div data-bind="with: person">
  <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
</div>
```

When the `person` observable is updated, even if to an entirely new `Person` object, the relevant bindings are re-evalutated, so the bindings on `<h1>` are checked again and applied against the new value of `person`, so it finds the "new" `name` property at that point.

At no point in your code are you setting `test.person` to be something *different*, you're updating the contents of the *observable it's already pointing at*.  If you did:

```
test.person = new Person();  //or
test.person = ko.observable(new Person(''));
```

It would no longer update the DOM, as you've broken the binding at that point, but because you only ever update the existing `person` observable, it's all fine.

Comment: But just to make sure I understand, "re-evaluating" the bindings is different than just reflecting the new value of the property, correct? I mean, ko is making a new binding to a new property and not merely saying "this was '4' and now it's '5' — there was a change of value".

Comment: When you change the `person` observable to a new `Person` object, yes - the entire innards of the `<div>` will be recreated and any bindings re-evaluated.  If you're just updating the `name` property on the current `person` object, it purely updates the text.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering; it's helping a lot.

One last question... Even if I change the `data-bind` to exist only on the `h1` and eliminate the `"with: person"` and bind with something like `data-bind="person().name"` it all still works.

So, KO knows even here that when the person object changes it should reconstruct the `h1` (because the div would be eliminated)? Is this because it sees that `person` (in the reference `"person().name"`) is an observable?

Comment: Yes - every time you data-bind something, it keeps track of all observables that were used in the chain.  Since `person()` is now in that data-bind, it knows that if it changes, it needs to re-evaluate the binding.